# Preload won't run on component imported to _layout

Tags: sapper

If I use a preload function in a component at the root of an app, how come it never runs?
From https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template/issues/94 I take it that this used to be a bug, but was fixed.

So I am having a bit of trouble understanding why this won't run:

_layout.svelte

```
import someComponent from 'someComponent.svelte';

<someComponent />
```

someComponent.svelte

```
<script context="module">
  export async function preload({ params, query }) {
    console.log("i ran")
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer here it seems the preload function is only run on routes. In order to get the the desired effect I could either run a fetch in the onMount function, or pass down the data from the api call from _layout to the desired component. The problem here however is that if you have a nested component structure, it might get quite messy passing down props through several components.

Answer (score 0):

From [Sapper docs](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Preloading),

> page components can have an optional preload function

`preload` does not run because `someComponent.svelte` is not a page component (i.e. it is not rendered in response to the user navigating to a route)